# How to run Android Emulator in AWS server(windows) ? as it does not support the accelerated mode

Tags: android, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, android-emulator

How to run Android Emulator in AWS server(windows) ?  as it does not support the accelerated mode and arm will be too slow, is there any other way to run the emulator in AWS server(Windows)